# How do I reset my Session in my query in order to show the entire collection again?

Tags: meteor

My MongoDB query results are affected by Sessions values e.g.`recipientsDetails.find({ paymentStatus:{$in: Session.get('pendingFilter')} }).fetch();`

These **pendingFilter Sessions** values are set to enable filtered results whereby only specific values from the collection are desired E.g. Display only: **Successfully paid transactions**, **failed transactions**, or **reversed transactions** etc.

By default, the `pendingFilter` Session value is empty, so when my page loads for the first time the entire collection(unfiltered) displays, however after I've used the various filtered functions and would now like to return the default state where the entire collection unfiltered displays, this seems to **FAIL**. 
Can someone kindly help explain why this isn't working and offer a solution?

Below is what my actual MongoDB query looks like followed by the yield:

```
var userIdCode = Meteor.userId(); 
var phoneNumber = Meteor.users.findOne({_id: userIdCode }, { fields: { "profile.telephoneNumber": 1 } },  {sort: {paymentDate: -1 }} ); 
var usersPhoneNumber = phoneNumber.profile.telephoneNumber; 

recipientsDetails.find({ 
                          paymentStatus:{                                                                            
                             $in: Session.get('pendingFilter')
                             },
                          recipientPaymentStatus: {
                              $in: Session.get('pendingFilter')
                             }
                        },                                                       
                        { $or: [ { payersNumber: usersPhoneNumber },                                                                 
                        { recipientNumber: usersPhoneNumber } ] }, 

                        {sort: {paymentDate: 'desc' }}).fetch();
```

The query above yeilds:

```
0:
  payersName: "Sa Acea"
  payersNumber: "+254705087633"
  paymentDate: "2019-03-28 22:38:30"
  paymentStatus: "Success"
  recipientPaymentStatus: "Reversed"
  recipientNumber: "+254705087633"
  _id: "D3gY4BoR2tvxdK4xv"
1:
  payersName: "Paul Acea"
  payersNumber: "+254705557688"
  paymentDate: "2019-03-28 22:38:30"
  paymentStatus: "Pending"
  recipientPaymentStatus: "Success"
  recipientNumber: "+254705087633"
  _id: "ajCjYbLaDP7x4iAFK"
2:
  payersName: "Simon Bolton"
  payersNumber: "+25470887633"
  paymentDate: "2019-03-28 22:38:30"
  paymentStatus: "Success"
  recipientPaymentStatus: "Complete"
  recipientNumber: "+254705087633"
  _id: "K4d6wDrjRRdSyCkhW"
```

I have three **filters** functions that when clicked shows only specified collection values. As seen below:

```
  'click .reversedSubMenu' (event, instance) {
      event.preventDefault();
      Session.set('pendingFilter', [ "Success", "Reversed" ]);
    },
```

This correctly yeilds:

```
0:
  payersName: "Sabiti Asea"
  payersNumber: "+254705087633"
  paymentDate: "2019-03-28 22:38:30"
  paymentStatus: "Success"
  recipientPaymentStatus: "Reversed"
  _id: "D3gY4BoR2tvxdK4xv"
```

.

```
   'click .inPescrowSubMenu' (event, instance) {
      event.preventDefault();
      Session.set('pendingFilter', [ "Success", "Pending" ]);
    },
```

This correctly yeilds:

```
0:
  payersName: "Paul Asea"
  payersNumber: "+254705557688"
  paymentDate: "2019-03-28 22:38:30"
  paymentStatus: "Pending"
  recipientPaymentStatus: "Success"
  _id: "ajCjYbLaDP7x4iAFK"
```

.

```
   'click .paidSubMenu' (event, instance) {
      event.preventDefault();
      Session.set('pendingFilter', [ "Success", "Complete" ]);
    },
```

This also correctly yeilds:

```
0:
  payersName: "Simon Bolton"
  payersNumber: "+25470887633"
  paymentDate: "2019-03-28 22:38:30"
  paymentStatus: "Success"
  recipientPaymentStatus: "Complete"
  _id: "K4d6wDrjRRdSyCkhW"
```

The **issue** here is that the below `.reset` function doesn't function as designed. When clicked, the `pendingFilter` session resets to null but I am not able to view the entire collection as desired.

```
   'click .reset' (event, instance) {
      event.preventDefault();
      Session.set('pendingFilter', []);
      var testing = Session.get('pendingFilter');
      console.log("Testing PendingFilter: " +testing )
    },
```

The above yields in the browser console: `Testing PendingFilter:`

The desired result after `.reset` is clicked is for the yeild to show the entire/unfiltered colleciton as seen below:

```
0:
  payersName: "Sabiti Asea"
  payersNumber: "+254705087633"
  paymentDate: "2019-03-28 22:38:30"
  paymentStatus: "Success"
  recipientPaymentStatus: "Reversed"
  recipientNumber: "+254705087633"
  _id: "D3gY4BoR2tvxdK4xv"
1:
  payersName: "Paul Asea"
  payersNumber: "+254705557688"
  paymentDate: "2019-03-28 22:38:30"
  paymentStatus: "Pending"
  recipientPaymentStatus: "Success"
  recipientNumber: "+254705087633"
  _id: "ajCjYbLaDP7x4iAFK"
2:
  payersName: "Simon Bolton"
  payersNumber: "+25470887633"
  paymentDate: "2019-03-28 22:38:30"
  paymentStatus: "Success"
  recipientPaymentStatus: "Complete"
  recipientNumber: "+254705087633"
  _id: "K4d6wDrjRRdSyCkhW"
```

How do I formulate my reset function/or the query to enable the above-desired result?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know why I didn't figure this out earlier, but all I had to do to **RESET**, was to simply add all the array values into the session as seen below:

```
   'click .reset' (event, instance) {
      event.preventDefault();
      Session.set('pendingFilter', [ "Pending", "Complete", "Success", "Reversed" ]);
      var testing = Session.get('pendingFilter');
      console.log("Testing PendingFilter: " +testing )
    },
```